# Clarification: The Google Calendar API v3 will now include the eventType parameter to subscribe to specific event types when using Events.Watch

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I recently had this email from Google saying:

> We are writing to inform you about upcoming changes to the Google Calendar API v3 that may impact your applications and notification handling, starting March 11, 2024.
>
> #### What does this mean for your organization?
>
> The Google Calendar API v3 will now include the `eventType` parameter to subscribe to specific event types when using `Events.Watch`. Additionally, starting March 11, 2024, the following changes will be introduced:
>
> - Default event type filters alignment for both `Events.list` and `Events.watch`.
> - Error handling for operations not supported for special event types, such as WorkingLocation, Out of Office, and FocusTime events.
>
> #### What do you need to do?
>
> To prevent any direct impact in your applications, we strongly encourage you to review your usage of the applications listed below and take the following actions:
>
> - `Events.watch`: Specify the event types you need for your application as a parameter to reduce your infrastructure costs. In
>   case you want to request a quota increase, please make sure you have
>   implemented event type filters appropriately. This factor will be
>   considered when we are evaluating quota increase requests.
> - `Events.list`: Specify the event types you need for your application as a parameter. Without making this change, working
>   location events will start to be returned.
> - Event type: If your code is performing operations on special events, it is important to review it to ensure that your code does not
>   attempt to perform operations not supported for special event types.

The email also states that I can reach out here for advice about this matter. I have a VB.Net console executable that create / deletes calendar events. And it makes use of the batch feature to perform actions in bulk.

As far as I am aware I am not using either:

- `Events.Watch`
- `Events.List`

What should I specifically look for in my project?